# Emphasizing Work on Resume Without Making It Obvious

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search

I've been working at an entry level IT position for a little over a year now. Over the past year I have wrote all the code for the new company website and did some design, and wrote all the code/did all the design for an Android and iOS app. I also do tier one support for 5 locations as well as lots of other small tasks. I would really like to apply for an app developer job and would like for my resume to show the work I've put in without it looking desperate. What is the best way to show this? Just as a side note, all 3 projects I've worked a lot on my own time as well and this is my first job out of college.

I should add that the apps are company apps not my own projects.

Comment: Just saying what you've been doing will not make you look desperate....

Comment: You wrote the code? Or you learned how to use Wordpress?... just clarifying

Comment: No I wrote all the code. I didn't use a website builder.

Comment: Well I was hoping to show that I essentially did most of the work on them besides the design work on the website. I didn't know if something like "sole developer" would look like I was trying too hard or look desperate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your CV is there to sell yourself. Its not desperate to display your skills.

The whole point of the document is to display your experience and capabilities and get your foot in the door for an interview.

Glorify yourself as much as you can.

Comment: ...as much as you can, as long as it's not too much. But the bar is very high, think about the positive vocabulary of the advertising world. Those ads actually work. Be as positive as them, not more(difficult to be more positive.....)

Answer (score 6):

You should absolutely make it obvious! Hiring managers usually review resumes on top of their day-to-day jobs and they need to get resume reviews over with quickly so they can get back to their actual jobs. If you make your qualifications  obvious that's helpful, you're showing that you understand what the manager wants and can present it clearly instead of making them dig for it.

I personally love seeing details of projects on a resume, just put them under "Projects" rather than "Experience" if they're personal projects. If it's a work project that you put extra time into, it could look weird to specifically mention that you worked on it outside of work hours, but you should definitely put those projects on your resume and you should go into detail about exactly what you did.

Answer (score 3):

The only way not to make it obvious you're selling your previous work is not to send the resume. Which, if you ask me, is a poor strategy to get a job.

Recruiters don't like modesty. They like past achievments  and skills you can tell them about. And there's nothing desperate about applying for a job and showing why you're a good fit for it (especially in IT which is a wonderful employment area where recruiters are typically more in demand than potential employees), it's job-hunting 101. Remember your resume will likely end up in a pool of 30 that some HR guy will screen in a few minutes total to select the 5-6 ones he's gonna look further into. Discretion is NOT the way you want to play this.